# Why does SQS Messages write and delete give wrong count?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I wrote the following code to write few messages into the SQS Queue and delete them immediately. However I see in the output that every message is deleted instantaneously. Nevertheless I see the message count appearing very randomly. I mean it showed 1 initially then it showed 2 again in spite of deleting one more.I have set the visibility timeout to 50 seconds like what is mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194293/sqs-messages-not-deleting). I tried the same as part of the program.

So my doubt is does the delete message happens immediately. If so how will that effect the thread count. Please see the code and output below.

```
__author__ = 'Dhanapathi.Marepalli'

import boto.sqs

conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("us-east-1", aws_access_key_id="********",
                                  aws_secret_access_key="************")
my_queue = conn.get_queue('SMSQueue')


def write_messages():
    print("Writing messages.")
    for i in range(1, 5):
        new_message = Message()
        message_body = str(random.randint(1111111111, 9999999999))
        print("Message body is ", message_body)
        new_message.set_body(message_body)
        my_queue.write(new_message)
        print("Message with message body {0} is written.".format(message_body))
    print("Messages completed. Totally {0} messages written to Queue.".format(my_queue.count()))


def retrieve_messages():
    while True:
        counter = 0
        rs = my_queue.get_messages()
        for message in rs:
            counter = 1
            body = message.get_body()
            print(current_thread().getName(), " Message is ", body)
            print(current_thread().getName(), " Assume something happened in between.")
            is_message_deleted = my_queue.delete_message(message)
            if is_message_deleted:
                print("{0}: Message with body {1} is deleted.".format(current_thread().getName(), body))
            else:
                print("{0}: Message with body {1} failed to delete.".format(current_thread().getName(), body))

            print(current_thread().getName(), " thread count is ", my_queue.count())

        if counter == 0:
            print("Thread1:No messages inside the Queue.")
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
   write_messages()
   retrieve_messages()
```

The output that was generated is as follows:

```
Writing messages.
Message body is  8111076750
Message with message body 8111076750 is written.
Message body is  4927934264
Message with message body 4927934264 is written.
Message body is  8511692382
Message with message body 8511692382 is written.
Message body is  9718698315
Message with message body 9718698315 is written.
Messages completed. Totally 4 messages written to Queue.
MainThread  Message is  8111076750
MainThread  Assume something happened in between.
MainThread: Message with body 8111076750 is deleted.
MainThread  thread count is  3
MainThread  Message is  4927934264
MainThread  Assume something happened in between.
MainThread: Message with body 4927934264 is deleted.
MainThread  thread count is  2
MainThread  Message is  9718698315
MainThread  Assume something happened in between.
MainThread: Message with body 9718698315 is deleted.
MainThread  thread count is  1
MainThread  Message is  8511692382
MainThread  Assume something happened in between.
MainThread: Message with body 8511692382 is deleted.
MainThread  thread count is  2
Thread1:No messages inside the Queue.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

SQS is a distributed system.  You want that for scale and reliability.  However, because of the distributed nature of the system it cannot guarantee 100% consistency.  To get the count of items in the queue, boto is using the queue attribute `ApproximateNumberOfMessages` which, as the name implies, can only provide an approximate count of the available messages in a queue.

If your application requires an exact count of the messages in the queue, SQS is probably not the right answer to your problem.  It is, however, an extremely reliable and scalable queueing service for applications that understand its consistency limitations.